# Tips on inputting coordinates into a data step with SAS?

Tags: sas, coordinates, proc-sql

```
Data Locations; 
input coordinates $; 
datalines;
35° 47' 29.5368' N and 78° 46' 52.0320' W.;
run;
```

How do I write the coordinates to where they are placed as one dataline?
I have tried double quotes, parentheses getting rid of all inner quotes. Maybe I should put something other then an input and dollar sign?

Comment: Make sure to put the semi-colon after the last line of data.  Your current program will read 0 lines of data because you added the semi-colon to the only line of data. The `run;` statement is not needed, but does not hurt anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do it with a data step. Notice I've set the Variable Length to 45 in all the examples.  These examples were tested in Windows SAS 9.4 only.

```
Data Locations;
input coordinates $ 1-45; 
datalines;
35° 47' 29.5368' N and 78° 46' 52.0320' W.
;
run;
```

or

```
Data Locations;
input coordinates $45.; 
datalines;
35° 47' 29.5368' N and 78° 46' 52.0320' W.
;
run;
```

SAS online docs ([Link](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0188182.htm)) have some pretty good examples of using the datalines statement.

Alternatively you could do this with proc sql, as below.

```
proc sql;
   create table Locations
          (coordinates char(45));
   insert into Locations
    values("35° 47' 29.5368' N and 78° 46' 52.0320' W.");
quit;
```

Some good examples on creating a table and inserting data into using the sql procedure can be found [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n1ncn0pznd8wrln1tnp3xdxjz9xz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n1ncn0pznd8wrln1tnp3xdxjz9xz).